# Git clone failure host key

Tags: git, chef-infra

I am attempting to run a delivery init on my chef repo and I am getting the below error.

```
Chef Delivery
Creating Delivery project...
  Skipping: Delivery project named project already exists.
Pushing initial git history...
Git command failed!
STDOUT:
STDERR: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have run a delivery setup and delivery token but it still fails with the same error.  I have also compared my public key to chef automate and my private key to my chef server and they are both the same.  Not sure where the issue is.

Also, this is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the host key is failing verification. If this is expected (i.e. the hostkey on the repo actually changed) then remove it from your known_hosts file. Otherwise, get out your tinfoil hat ...

Comment: The keys match though between the server and my local key.